# Return code in windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, batch-file, scheduler

I have a batch script which triggers an executable jar file. The batch runs for a polling time say 5 mins. I created a task in the scheduler and triggered the batch file. The batch executed successfully but i didnt get the return code in the scheduler. My question is how do i return the [image]code from the batch file to the scheduler. Please help!

Comment: Look into adding `exit %ERRORLEVEL%` right after the execution. Note that you should make sure that your apps exists with the correct code.

Comment: I have given a time of 3 mins..The batch stops at 3 min. I am not able to view the errorlevel. I tried writing the error level to a file, even that did'nt work